# Xcode says local is out of date, but I am trying to completely replace the GitHub repo

Tags: xcode, github

I wrote a tiny application [and checked it into GitHub](https://github.com/maurymarkowitz/Spriteoscope). I then wanted to make it cross-platform, so instead of trying to build that out, I restarted with a new project and selected Multiplatform->Game. As part of this I made a new local repo, and once it was up and running, connected it to the remote.

Now the new project is very different than the old one. And so when I try to Push, it complains that "The local repository is out of date." I tried doing a Pull with Stash, and that happened without any errors, but I still get the same error when trying to push. A Refresh File Status indicates no changes.

Reading many (many!) threads here suggests that it should just work, you should be able to completely rebuild a remote just by pushing. So I suspect the issue is in Xcode? Any advice on how to get this code into the repo?

Comment: Why not just delete the GitHub repo and make a new one?

Comment: Alternatively, since your github repo has just one branch, you could push that branch with force — `get switch main; git push -f origin main`

Comment: @matt - I tried this. Checking in gives "The local repository is out of date." Trying to pull gives "An unknown error occurred. no merge base found (-3)"

Comment: Wow. Ok, the entire problem was the LICENSE file. It was unchanged on both ends, and showed no status changes, but deleting it and doing a pull cleared the error.

Comment: You may wish to delete the question

Comment: Why? Might help the next one.

Comment: Not if you don't also _answer_ the question. Don't leave it hanging open.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new repo and select a license, the resulting LICENCE file will always conflict with the local even if there are no differences. This is not indicated in the Xcode display, nor does github report any differences online or in the CLI.

So... if you are making a new repo, do not select a license if the project contains one.